# Which HTTP method to use for RESTful api for "add to cart" an existing item already in cart?

Tags: rest, http-post, addition, shopping-cart, cart

I have started designing addToCart method as HTTP POST in my RESTful API. This looks good when the client adds to cart a product first time (POST create a new entry on server). But, the same HTTP rule breaks when the client browses through the site and adds the same item again; where we should not create a new entry but only update the quantity of existing item.

Isn't using POST to update resource wrong? What is the way to implement this? or how to interpret this situation.

Note: Client/UI front which uses my api would not remember if its already there on server. Please consider any ecommerce application's addtocart as example.

Comment: why not just check if there is already the same product in the cart and then if it is, update it, otherwise add new one.

Comment: I can do that on the same POST. But, won't that be HTTP POST method violation as POST specification says creates entry on server for every POST request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the difficulties here are already present in how you add the original item to the cart.

When you add an item to cart, are you creating a new object (the item)? Or are you modifying an existing item (the cart)? To me it makes more sense to say the latter. POSTing an item seems like it should be reserved for a different situation, when you add a new item to your store.

Conceptually, the cart is then like a vector of all the items in your store, associated with a number (0 for almost all of them). Adding something to the cart means incrementing this number for one of the items, regardless of whether it is already more than 0.

Comment: thanks jwg. you have shown me how to look from different angle. this helps me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PATCH` to send a part object / update to an existing object.

Comment: Client/UI consuming my RESTful service will not know if the product is already in cart. How to deal with this?

Comment: Surely you're sending the product ID? The API will the determine if it's to add or update the qty...

Comment: Yes. As per Specification POST is for add and PATCH is for partial update. Won't it be updating quantity on POST method a violation as per the spec?

Comment: Using POST to update a product qty in a basket is perfectly fine too.

Answer (score 0):

It's based on your model. IMHO a POST is also fine if you are modelling a new intent or cart-operation with it, which can be basically anything.